# UIImageView is not instantiated in DetailViewController

Tags: swift

I am writing a master-detail application. When table row item is clicked, I load the image in the DetailViewController, which has a UIImageView. I assume the UIImageView is instantiated by app and I only need to set the UIImage.

```
imageView.image = UIImage(name:"camera")
```

However, the imageView is nil. I sure that the imageView is linked with UIImageView on storyboard.

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

func configureView() {

    if !imageView {
        println("nilnilnil") // nilnilnil is printed...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the view has already been loaded. You should at least wait until after `viewDidLoad`. Usually you would do this directly in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.imageView.image = UIImage(name: "camera")
}
```

This is because the subviews are not created and the connections are not setup  until the view is loaded. The view is not loaded until the `view` property of the view controller is accessed – usually, this is when the view controller is presented for the first time.

**Minor Note:** A variable is "instantiated" or "initialized" not "instanced"

Comment: The function configureView() is generated by Xcode using master-detail template and it is executed inside viewDidLoad(). However, it is also called after detail item is set and ImageView is not initialized in that time. I finally add a nil checking of imageView before setting the image instance